# pandas describe 0.18.0 vs pandas describe 0.17.0

Tags: python, pandas

On one environment, I have pandas version 0.17.0 with numpy version 1.10.1.
On another environment, I have pandas version 0.18.1 with numpy version 1.10.4.

I run this piece of code

```
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np
Series([1,2,3,4,5,np.NaN]).describe()
```

With pandas version 0.17.0 I get this output:

```
count    5.000000 
mean     3.000000
std      1.581139
min      1.000000
25%      2.000000
50%      3.000000
75%      4.000000
max      5.000000
dtype: float64
```

with pandas version 0.18.1 i get this output:

```
count    5.000000
mean     3.000000
std      1.581139
min      1.000000
25%           NaN
50%           NaN
75%           NaN
max      5.000000
dtype: float64
```

what gives?

Comment: additional info.  python installation is the Anaconda distribution.  I created the environments with conda

Comment: `pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,np.NaN]).describe()` in my system (`pd.__version__` returns `0.18.0`) returns the proper quantiles...?

Comment: what's your numpy version for the 2 examples? Mine is `1.10.4`

Comment: for environment with correct output .  1.10.1.   for environment with incorrect output 1.10.4

Comment: @cyth217 Pandas 0.18.0 or 0.18.1? Also, SciPy versions?

Comment: @Donkey Kong.  I made an error, it's actually pandas 0.18.1

Comment: @Donkey Kong.  I made an error, it's actually pandas 0.18.1  For correct output i have scipy 0.16.0.  I for incorrect output i have scipy 0.17

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that `Series.describe()` uses `Series.quantile()`, and there is currently a [reported bug (*#13098*)](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13098) in Pandas 0.18.1 where `Series.quantile()` will not return percentiles when the series contains `nan`.

Bug demo from #13098:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, numpy.nan])
>>> s.quantile(0.5)
nan
```

If you look at [pull #12752](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/12752) it looks like `notnull` used to be used to remove the `nan` values before calculating percentiles, however it was removed.

---

**Update**:

This issue now appears to be closed with [this commit](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/4de83d25d751d8ca102867b2d46a5547c01d7248) after which `Series.quantile()` once again handles `nan` *(2016/05/12)*.